# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at demo.Lookup.main(Lookup.java:19)

Tags: java, networking

```
package demo;
import java.net.*;

public class Lookup {
    private InetAddress inet = null;
    public void resolve(String host){
        try{
            inet = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            System.out.println("Host name :" +inet.getHostName());
            System.out.println("IP Address:" +inet.getHostAddress());
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Lookup lookup = new Lookup();
        lookup.resolve(args[0]);
    }
}
```

And I got:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at demo.Lookup.main(Lookup.java:19)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a Command Line argument supplied to your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "args" from the main method is passing in by parameter

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Assuming that you are compiling the codes using command line:

```
javac demo\Lookup.java (I am using windows here)
```

you can pass in the parameter when you execute the codes using command line

```
java demo.Lookup <lookup ip address here>
```

if you are using IDE such as Eclipse, you can configure your "Run Configuration" to pass in IP address in the "Program Arguments"

[image: eclipse configuration]

Answer (score 0):

No args are passed into your args parameter wherever you are calling this function. So when you try to get the first value, there is nothing there.

Comment: emm... how can i fix this? would u like to give me an example? i m a freshman

Comment: Wherever you call the class in your program, pass in a string array with at least one element. That way when it calls `args[0]`, there is something there.

Comment: i add like:  `args[0] = "129.11.144.10"; ` but still not working